# Do nothing on empty input - combinate with dynamic action on form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

What i want is when you type something in `input`, depending what button you click,  he will change path of action in `form`. I am at half way to achieve this (i think)....check out what i make till now

```js
function OnSubmitForm() {
      if(document.pressed == 'Log As')
      {
       document.myform.action ="log-as.html";
      }
      else
      if(document.pressed == 'Log As Int')
      {
        document.myform.action ="log-as-int.html";
      }
      return true;
    };
```

```html
<form name="account" onsubmit="return onsubmitform();">
  <input type="text" name="user" id="user">
  <input type="submit" name="account" onclick="document.pressed=this.value" value="Log As" />
  <input type="submit" name="account" onclick="document.pressed=this.value" value="Log As Int" />
</form>
```

And maybe i found solution for this, but i don't know how to combinate those two...

```js
$('#search-form').submit(function(e) {
   if (!$('#user').val()) {
       e.preventDefault();
   }       
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same thing by using this code:

> First of all `name` attribute of your form and `input type submit` are
>   same. They must be unique.

```
<form name="account" id="account" action="">
  <input type="text" name="user" id="user">
  <input type="submit" name="account_submit1" onclick="document.pressed=this.value" value="Log As" />
  <input type="submit" name="account_submit2" onclick="document.pressed=this.value" value="Log As Int" />
</form>
```

and

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#account").submit(function(e){
            alert($.trim($("#account [type='submit']:focus").val()))
            if($.trim($("#account [type='submit']:focus").val()) == "Log As"){
                $("#account").attr('action',"log-as.html");
                }else{
                $("#account").attr('action',"log-as-int.html");
            }
        });
    });
```

Updated code according to the discussion:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#account").submit(function(e){
             if (!$('#user').val()) {
               e.preventDefault();
             }  
            if($.trim($("#account [type='submit']:focus").val()) == "Log As"){
                $("#account").attr('action',"log-as.html");
                }else{
                $("#account").attr('action',"log-as-int.html");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Sorry for my late replay. Not good my friend, or im getting all this wrong? From here i got 2nd JS code [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GgEZc/) . So when input is empty nothing happens when you click on button

Comment: @Soullighter This is validation part you can also use it in the above code

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily done using JQuery like so:

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
    var name = $(this).val();
    if(name=="Log As"){
        $("#myform").attr('action', 'log-as.html');
    }
    if(name=="Log As Int"){
        $("#myform").attr('action', 'log-as-int.html');
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/koqdLw96/)

I would also like to point out that you are submitting to a HTML page and not a PHP page. So do keep that in mind when trying to retrieve the values later.

Comment: That was just example ( speaking about HTML submit ), because project is still in process, will change later ;)

Comment: Alright, :) Do let me know if the solution works for you though.

Comment: Sorry for my late replay. Not good my friend, or im getting all this wrong? From here i got 2nd JS code [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GgEZc/) . So when input is empty nothing happens when you click on button

Comment: Yes, the code `e.preventDefault();` in the JSFiddle you provided stops the form from being submitted in case the search box is blank.